# Race condition when combining async action and accessing local state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Suppose I have a list of items I would like to render and select (like a Todo app).

I'd like to keep the selection logic inside custom react hook and have items live somewhere else in local state.

Now, I would like to update the selection list, kept in the custom hook, whenever I fetch some more items. For this task I am passing data as parameter to selection hook and I am using `useEffect` to update the selection:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const itemsArrayToObject = (items) =>
  Object.fromEntries(items.map((i) => [i.id, { ...i, selected: false }]));

export function useSelection({ data }) {
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState(itemsArrayToObject(data));

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelection((selection) => {
      return {
        ...itemsArrayToObject(data),
        ...selection
      };
    });
  }, [data]);

  const isSelected = (itemId) => selection?.[itemId]?.selected ?? false;

  const toggle = (itemId) => {
    setSelection((s) => {
      const item = s[itemId];
        return {
          ...s,
          [itemId]: {
            ...item,
            selected: !item.selected
          }
        };
    });
  };

  return {
    isSelected,
    toggle
  };
}
```

This almost works but the problem is if I want to synchronize two things: fetching data and toggling items. Eg.

```
  const onLoadAndToggle = async () => {
    await load();

    toggle(0);
  };
```

`load` is a async function that fetches the data. It also triggers state update so that `data` is updated and the selection can be updated inside `useSelection` hook.
Example how it all can work:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const addItems = (items) => {
    setData((state) => [...state, ...items]);
  };

  const { load } = useFetch({ addItems });

  const { isSelected, toggle } = useSelection({ data });

  const onLoadAndToggle = async () => {
    await load();

    toggle(0);
  };
```

Now, the problem is that when calling `toggle(0)` my custom hook has a stale selection, even when using `setState(state => ...` singature.
It is because the whole fetching and updating `data` in state takes too long.

I can see some ugly ways to solve that problem but I wonder what would be the elegant or idiomatic react way to solve that.

I have made a code sandbox, if it helps: https://codesandbox.io/s/selection-fetch-forked-nyl0kt?file=/src/App.js:376-512
Try clicking "Load and toggle first" first to see how the app crashed because the selection is not yet updated.

Comment: A quick solution would be to check `item` for null after retrieving and ignore if it's undefined. Another option could be to disable or hide the button until the list is loaded (since you're using `await` you don't really know when that's going to finish, specially if it goes to the backend.

Comment: @Alejandro thank you for the answer. Please note that that checking for null will only fix the crashing - but the first item won't be selected - which is what I would like to achieve

Comment: @Alejandro regarding the await - I'm not sure I understand - as soon as the next line after await I know the items are already fetched - it's the react state update that is causing the problem I think

Comment: `the first item won't be selected` that's because if you click too early there are no items yet, hence nothing to select, which is sort of correct for me. About `await`, after that line it's finished for sure, but since you're `await`ing other code can run **while** it's running (that's it, after the await began but before it finishes). At that time your page has still no data. If you need the consistency of button click = select an item, my second suggestion comes in: disable the button and only enable it after the `await` ended.

Comment: I don't think you understand the problem but thank you nevertheless :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to `initialize` toogled items from the code itself. We can do this by providing the `id's` of the items that we want to toggle to the hook itself.

Updated hook -

```
const itemsArrayToObject = (items, itemsToggled) => {
  if (Array.isArray(itemsToggled)) {
    return Object.fromEntries(
      items.map((i) => [i.id, { ...i, selected: itemsToggled.includes(i.id) }])
    );
  }
  return Object.fromEntries(
    items.map((i) => [i.id, { ...i, selected: false }])
  );
};
export function useSelection({ data }, itemsToggled) {
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState(
    itemsArrayToObject(data, itemsToggled)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelection((selection) => {
      return {
        ...itemsArrayToObject(data, itemsToggled),
        ...selection
      };
    });
  }, [data, itemsToggled]);
```

Now call to hook becomes -

```
const { isSelected, toggle } = useSelection({ data }, [0, 1]);
```

Updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/selection-fetch-forked-vl20o6?file=/src/App.js)

This also **decouples** loading data & toggling of an item initially.

Comment: The problem is I don't know which items I want to toggled on the initialization - I want this to be dynamic (to be honest my case is different - I want to every item to be selected but that does not matter)
I am not sure how your code solves my problem - I open the sandbox you linked, click "Load and toggle first" and still see the same error

Comment: The array can be dynamic, [0,1] is just to demonstrate. You will have some logic to find which items are toggled right? Also this does not be an array, you can send a function, object etc. 
The codesandbox works, the is no need for the separate button. I have removed it, you can check now.

Comment: @apieceofbart https://codesandbox.io/s/selection-fetch-forked-vl20o6

Comment: Actually I won't have any logic, since I wanted all of the items to be selected - I made simplified example in the question.
So in essence - I want to have one button that would only load additional items and another one that would load all items and select all of them right after loading

Comment: I wanted to make a simple example but I see that I confused everyone, sorry for that

Comment: And obviously I don't want to provide an array of ids since I don't know how many will load at once etc.

Comment: Even if we leave our the "toggle all" for a bit - check this sandbox that I made from your sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/selection-fetch-forked-5efhqc?file=/src/App.js
it precisely shows the problem - now, useEffect has `toggleId` as dependency and each change to it will change the selection - but that's not what we want, we want the selection to be determined only before fetching